# Ambiguity in sentence

Tags: ambiguity

Can different phrases be related to a same noun, modifying it and how to avoid ambiguity? E.g I remember man playing guitar that (this clause is related to "man", not "guitar") sounded good

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can, but there is no reliable way of avoiding ambiguity.

A possibility that sometimes works is start a new breath group (represented by a comma):

> I remember a man playing a guitar that sounded good *(probably the guitar)*

> I remember a man playing a guitar, that sounded good *(probably the playing)*.

But even then, my "probably" indicates that these interpretations are not forced, in either case.

Note that I have inserted the articles which you omitted, and which are required in English.

Comment: you can use "who" instead of "that" to specify the person